# Expected value $e^2$

Tags: regression, econometrics

Can someone help me to proof this equality about the square of the regression error?
$$Ee^2=E(y-x^Tb)=Ey^2-2E(yx^T)b$$

This expression is found in Hansen's book on Econometrics. The author seeks to proof the finiteness of $E (xe)$, which is one of the properties of the best linear projection. Below I put an image of the complete proof:

[image]

Comment: Where does this come from? Is the equation without tyop's?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Hansen's Econometrics Book.

Comment: A link to the formula would be helpful. At the very least, you might state the assumptions and define variables.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/ page 59.

Comment: I do not see the particular equation on page 59. Also, it is not useful to have details behind a 6MB pdf file. Could you describe the *entire* problem in your question.

Comment: There are a lot of forms of the same book published in different years. Can you please fully describe the problem or show *exactly* where you got it from?

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus How is third equality achieved? How do you remove the term $b^TE(xx^T)b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: forget random variables and their expectations to keep it simple :)

\begin{align*}
\beta &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\\
e^2 &= (y-X\beta)^2=y^2-2y^TX\beta+\beta^TX^TX\beta \\
&= y^2-2y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty+y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty \\
&= y^2-2y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty+y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty \\
&= y^2-y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
\end{align*}

Now replace non stochastic data with random variables and their expectations, e.g. replace $X^TX$ with $E[xx^T]$, and remember that $\beta=(E[xx^T])^{-1}E[xy]$ and $E[xx^T]$ is symmetric.

NB: The third equality is $=E[y^2]-E[yx^T](E[xx^T])^{-1}E[xy]$, not $=E[y^2]-2E[yx^T](E[xx^T])^{-1}E[xy]$:

[image]

Comment: thanks, so is there a typo in the text? Shouldn't it be a -2, but a minus -1?

Comment: @JavierMariño Wait a moment. I'll include a picture from my copy.

Comment: @JavierMariño Done. You can also look at the [pdf](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478732/properties-best-linear-projection